# Pass JSON to a data-model attribute in Thymeleaf

Tags: json, thymeleaf

So I have an element like

```
<input type="text" />
```

Now for testing purposes **in the template** I need to pass a JSON **literal** to a data-model attribute of that input:

JSON:

```
{ "disabled": true, "title": "my beautiful input" }
```

So I need the `th:attr` binding here:

```
<input type="text" th:attr="" />
```

In what format/escaping do I have to pass the `data-model` in the `th:attr` binding if all I have is the literal?

I would like Thymeleaf to create this output:

```
<input type="text" data-model='{ "disabled": true, "title": "my beautiful input" }' />
```

I need an output that allows me to use `JSON.parse()` on the attribute value in the frontend.

Comment: I don't understand.  What exactly have you added to the model (`model.put("??", "???")`) and what exactly do you want the output of the html to look like?

Comment: @Metroids Added the expected/desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (parses just fine using `JSON.parse`):

```
<input type="text" th:attr="data-model='{ &quot;disabled&quot;: true, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;my beautiful input&quot; }'" />
```

Although, if you're simply hard coding that attribute, I fail to see why you don't just use:

```
<input type="text" data-model='{ "disabled": true, "title": "my beautiful input" }' />
```

to begin with (also works with Thymeleaf).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it like the following:

```
<div th:attr="data-model=${json}">
```

Comment: I need to pass the literal, I don't have it in a template variable.